# Mimedata of dynamic qml object is always empty

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a treeview from which I drag items to a drop area by creating draggable items dynamically. Everything works except I cannot pass mimedata

```
function createItem(parentItem)
{
    if (itemComponent.status === Component.Ready && draggedItem == null)
    {
        draggedItem = itemComponent.createObject(
            parentItem,
            {
                "x": positionInParent.x,
                "y": positionInParent.y,
                "baseColor":Qt.lighter("red", 1.5),
                "copyable":false,
                visible: true
            }
        );

        draggedItem.Drag.mimeData = { "text/plain": "Hello!" };
        draggedItem.Drag.supportedActions = Qt.CopyAction;
        draggedItem.Drag.dragType = Drag.Automatic;
        draggedItem.Drag.start();
    }
    else if (itemComponent.status === Component.Error) {
        draggedItem = null;
        console.log("error creating component");
        console.log(itemComponent.errorString());
    }
}
```

when I try to get the mime data from drop event (drop.text field) it is empty.

```
DropArea
{
    height:parent.height
    width:parent.width
    onDropped: {
        drop.acceptProposedAction()
        var txt = drop.text; // Empty!!!
        console.log("dropped into dest")
    }
    onEntered: {
        console.log("entered dest")
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need `DragEvent.formats`? From the docs: `This property holds a list of mime type formats contained in the drag data`

Comment: @folibis I believe a format is added automatically when I call draggedItem.Drag.mimeData = { "text/plain": "Hello!" };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it myself! Just to add

```
draggedItem.Drag.active = true;
```